# Regex to get word before and after given word

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Can someone please help with regex pattern for below string in Python? I have `.log` file and I want to find below line from string I have to get user and ip.

I want regex that can get me one word before `from` and one after `from`.

```
Failed password for root from 123.183.209.132 port 39706 ssh2
```

I want `root` and `123.183.209.132` from above string

```
Failed password for invalid user packer from 13.82.211.217 port 45832 ssh2
```

I want `packer` and `13.82.211.217` from above string

```
reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for undefined.datagroup.ua
[93.183.207.5] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!

reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for nsg-static-226.127.71.182.airtel.in [182.71.127.226] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!

reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for 179.185.44.168.static.gvt.net.br [179.185.44.168] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
```

I want `undefined.datagroup.ua` and `93.183.207.5` from(new regex).

My working code.

```
def parse(filename, date=None):
    try:
        # string = 'Failed password for ([a-z]*|[a-z]* [a-z]* [a-z]*) from '
        string = 'Failed password for ([a-z]*|[a-z]* [a-z]* [a-z]*) from [0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}'
        # string_sub = 'for (?<user>[a-zA-Z\.]+).*?(?<ip>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})'
        # string_re = re.compile(r"^[^ ]+ - (C[^ ]*) \[([^ ]+)").match
        match_list =[]
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                for match in re.finditer(string, line, re.S):
                    match_text = match.group()
                    user_ip = re.search(r'Failed password for .*?(\w+) from (\d+(?:\.\d+){3})', match_text)
                    user = user_ip.groups()[0]
        print(user)
    except KeyError as e:
        msg="key %s is missing" % str(e)
        return msg
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

I'm stuck with regex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: I have edited my question I'm stuck with getting user and ip both form string.

Comment: I'm done with regex for 1st part I only need regex for 2nd string part. Can anyone help with only one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import re

inp = [
    'Failed password for root from 123.183.209.132 port 39706 ssh2',
    'Failed password for invalid user packer from 13.82.211.217 port 45832 ssh2',
    '''reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for undefined.datagroup.ua
[93.183.207.5] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!''',
]
for s in inp:
    result = re.search(r'(?:Failed password|reverse mapping.+?) for .*?([\w.]+)\s+(?:from |\[)(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})', s)
    print result.groups()
```

**Output:**

```
('root', '123.183.209.132')
('packer', '13.82.211.217')
('undefined.datagroup.ua', '93.183.207.5')
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                     # non capture group
    Failed password     # literally
  |                   # OR
    reverse mapping     # literally
    .+?                 # 1 or more any character, not greedy
)                       # end group
 for                    # literally
 .*?                    # 0 or more any character
 ([\w.]+)               # group 1, 1 or more word character or dot
 \s+                    # 1 or more spaces
 (?:from |\[)           # non capture group, from OR opening square bracket
(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})       # group 2, IP
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for above string. I need the same for below given string also `reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for undefined.datagroup.ua
[93.183.207.5] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!`.

Answer (score 0):

Regex may be overkill for your use case... Did you try simpler things, like this, for instance:

```
s1 = "Failed password for root from 123.183.209.132 port 39706 ssh2"
s2 = "Failed password for invalid user packer from 13.82.211.217 port 45832 ssh2"

parsed = s1.split('from',1)
user = parsed[0].split()[-1]
ip = parsed[1].split()[0]

print(f'User is {user} and IP is {ip}')
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you basically want the word (username) after `for` and the `ip` of that line? If that's the case, how about:

```
for (?<user>[a-zA-Z\.]+).*?(?<ip>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})
```

https://regex101.com/r/aojbyS/1. Granted, this is a short-hand form for an IP, but to make it more correct you should use a proper [ipv4 regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html).

Additionally, in your question, you don't say what should be captured from the following, which might modify the above regex.

```
Failed password for invalid user packer from 13.82.211.217 port 45832 ssh2.
```

Comment: it would be easy if I get one word before and after word `from`.

Comment: @aakankshakhandelwal but your last example doesn't contain the word from at all?

Comment: There are two different string so I will need two different regex. 1. to `regex.sub()` to get user and ip from string. 2. to get object and ip from 2nd string.